# set string as a global variable

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am trying to get values from a prompt alert input box and send the input value to another function, i could able to open prompt, and on button click able to import values to input field on clicking "Login" button i could view it on my console,

i need to declare a global variable and access it when ever i need to use it within this page

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, AlertController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { HomePage } from '../home/home';



@Component({
    selector: 'page-login',
    templateUrl: 'login.html'
})

export class LoginPage {

    FileName: Array<Object>;

    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController,
                public alertCtrl: AlertController,
                public navParams: NavParams,
                ) { }

presentPrompt() {
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Login',
                inputs: [
                    {
                        name: 'FileName',
                        placeholder: 'Rename Your Audio File'
                    }
                ],
            buttons: [
                {
                    text: 'Cancel',
                    role: 'cancel',
                    handler: data => {
                        console.log('Cancel clicked');
                    }
                },
                {
                    text: 'Login',
                    handler: data => {
                        console.log("login clicked");
                       this.FileName = data.FileName + '.mp3';

                    }
                }
            ]
        });
            alert.present();
    }

    getValue(){
         console.log("trying to get value", this.FileName);       
       // value from prompt must be send to the above console
    }
```

What i need is the "FileName" value inside input field should be viewed when "getvalue" is clicked. could some one help me

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you need some *global available stuff*, you have to put it into a `Service`.

In your case create a service which will hold a simple string property which can be get and set. Then inject that service into your component. The lifetime of the service last for whole time your angular app is running and the value can be read/written by every component (or other service) where it will be injected.

Comment: I dont know how to write a service i am not that much familiar with angular2